# call each other methods inside the interface in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

Newbie on typescript here .

I have interface and methods written in typescript.
I want to call another function inside another function.
How can we do that in Typescript.

```
export interface InterfaceProps {
  someFunction1(): Promise<boolean>;
}

export const someClass: InterfaceProps {
 async someFunction1(): Promise<boolean> {
    someFunction2(); // This is not allowed right now. But how can i acheive this.
 }

 async someFunction2(): Promise<boolean> {
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you change the code to at least use valid syntax?

Comment: Fixing any unrelated errors, I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nr8a3W). The `satisfies` keyword cannot be used here since it has excess properties, so a generic helper function is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest the following solutions:

```
export interface InterfaceProps {
  someFunction1(): Promise<boolean>;
  someFunction2(): Promise<boolean>;
}


export const someClass1: InterfaceProps = {
 someFunction1: async(): Promise<boolean> => {
    return someClass1.someFunction2() // function call in the someFunction1 and return Promise boolean
 },
 someFunction2: async (): Promise<boolean> => Promise.resolve(true), // Function return Promise boolean
}

// OR

export const someClass2: InterfaceProps = {
 someFunction1: async(): Promise<boolean> => {
    someClass2.someFunction2() // function call in the someFunction1
    return Promise.resolve(true) // return Promise boolean
 },
 someFunction2: async (): Promise<boolean> => Promise.resolve(true), // Function return Promise boolean
}
```

Please note that I use arrow functions and I advise you to do this.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSRTS1wAUoIwBnOAbwCg44qIBbYAMQFclsYEISAIwAKAJQAuOOTYIqwADwAjCBAA2wTEgB8AbkbM2nHnwFIATOKkzWcxSvWad+gL713oSLDjZBVeCzsAMJqmFRUQlKEqBg4wDLUcAC8dIyBxrz8gpFwYQCevFbSFLbyyqoaWtrJ1QxMTFDAMFxQSIbBoeFCAHTp3JlmlmJwAPQjcOgmWW3YmGpqiG0wABZ4fVNmQrlIACZwjc2txbLycA6VSIwuADRpRv2mguZS+bxwRTZ25Y5VNcelwG6jRYagAbsARDAoFxgGJrqNxg9pvsmi02p9TucnPQ3PQxnAAPIAJQ84Gg8F8SH87WAITCVGeBCIsTIFESKTq6wG2ReVAK2A+JS+WN+SVqBiY6Tp4XMvXuGye4gREwVMzmC2QcBWa3l3OEEpRh3RQvkQOAIPBkOhsOVBzR-zsZwq2LgNzu7CRg15-PekgdZRFOj+GMBwPUlqhMLhys9gkN9pDTp+lxcQA)

Answer (score -1):

You getting error because you define `Promise<boolean>` type for `someFunction1` returning value and you should inside the function at the end return a promise (type of boolean), also you are forgotten to define `someFunction2` in InterfaceProps interface:

```
export interface InterfaceProps {
  someFunction1(): Promise<boolean>;
  someFunction2(): Promise<boolean>;
}

export const someClass: InterfaceProps = {
  async someFunction1(): Promise<boolean> {
    return await this.someFunction2();
  },
  async someFunction2(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 1000));
  },
};
```

But if you won't to return something and assume void do it like below:

[image]

Comment: Did you try your code in the playground? This doesn't answer the question either since you still can't use the `someFunction2` method in `someFunction1`.

Comment: I updated the answer, generally that was correct but there are some another mistakes on the code, so for better understanding I added screen shot of an example from that on a playground to answer.

Comment: Your playground code completely changes the interface defined in the question, as well as the function signatures, especially by turning the return type into void which means that the playground code won't help OP whatsoever.

Comment: Although I explained "if you won't to return something" use the approach but I added a sample with *Promise* to the answer too.